# How to develop on a branch in HG?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, dvcs

I would like to do some experimental work in a hg project. So I would like to create branch, commit to it. And if the experiment works, I can merge it back to main branch.

In git, I can do

```
$ git branch experimental
$ git checkout experimental
(edit file)
$ git commit -a
$ git checkout master
```

I've read [A Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/). It said `hg branch feature`. But what is next?
I don't follow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$ hg branch experimental

(edit file)
$ hg commit
$ hg update default
```

Comment: Do I need to hg commit all the changes I made in 'default' before I do 'hg branch experimental'?

Comment: Yeah--you do, assuming you want the pending changes to go in the default branch. Otherwise, the pending changes follow you over to the branch that you've named "experimental", and you can commit them there.

Comment: you will need to "hg merge experimental" once you update back to default here too, I believe.

Comment: "experimental" should be considered a simplification, not a good branch name. If you call it "experimental" when developing feature X, what will you call it when you experiment around feature Y? Named branches in mercurial should be used with care, not to pollute the branch namespace.

Answer (score 21):

First note that `git branch` is **different** from [`hg branch`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#branch). Branches created with `hg branch` are permanent and live in a global name space, whereas branches made with `git branch` are transient. The nearest equivalent of `git branch` is [`hg bookmark`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#bookmarks): bookmarks can be renamed and deleted and behave more like Git-branches.

I've recently written a [guide for Mercurial bookmarks](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/bookmarks/). Compare this with the [named branch guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/). Both guides contain worked examples of how to use (named) branches in Mercurial for keeping track of the development. It shows how to merge branches and how to close them or delete the bookmark when you are done.

Comment: Useful walk through for named branches, though it is also useful to be aware of anonymous branches (as Tomislav points out).

Comment: @NathanAdams: Thanks for pointing out the broken link! A comment would have been enough to get my attention, no down-vote necessary.

Comment: I downvoted because due to the broken link the answer wasn't correct anymore. And since I downvoted I always leave a comment. I see you have fixed the link and you have a +1 from me.

Comment: @Will: yeah, I much prefer the comment over a deleted answer :-) I don't understand why you would delete the answer, though. Even with a (slightly) broken link, it is still correct and useful to people.

Comment: @MartinGeisler: I agree, thus bringing this conversation back to my original comment!  A nice, tidy package, all wrapped up.

Comment: @MartinGeisler The bookmarks tutorial was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If it's not a big feature (i.e. the branch doesn't have to have a name), it's quite simple.

Let's say your repository is at changeset X. You work on the feature as much as you like, commit, commit, commit and if you're happy with the result, continue as if you knew it would work all along. ;) If you aren't happy, do a `hg update X` and continue development from there. All the work you did on your experiment will become an anonymous branch.

Strangely enough, it [appears](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-anonymously) that Git doesn't provide such a way to work with anonymous branches which is what might be confusing you.

Comment: Also, Mercurial documentation, particularly in the hg wiki, is a little imprecise and potentially confusing in this area.  What you are calling `anonymous branches` are cases of what Mercurial calls `heads`.  A `head` is a changeset without a child.  A changeset always belongs to one and only one named branch; that might be the default branch, whose name is `default`.  A named branch always has at least one `head` but it may have more.  By doing an `hg update X` and a commit, you create a new head in the named branch to which X belongs, but the head is not a branch in hg's sense of `branch`.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right: Mercurial calls "heads" the leaf revisions of branches and calls "anonymous branches" branches which have not been explicitly named. The fact that a "named branch" usually consists of a number of anonymous branches doesn't help anyone to easily understand it, but that is how it works...

Comment: The current `hg` man page is the closest thing to a definitive word on the subject and that's the only place where the term "anonymous branch" is used in the hg source.  The man page glossary tries to distinguish between the terms "branch head", "repository head", and "topological head" as well as "named branch" vs "anonymous branch" vs "topological branch".  It certainly can be confusing and difficult to explain with precision due to the overloading of terms.  Fortunately, most of the time it doesn't matter too much.